# weird background in grouped table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, background-color

We use in our application cells in a grouped tableview as buttons. Therefore we set a backgroundimage to look the cells like buttons. We used the following code:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_gradient_mainmenu_2.png"]];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

which looks like this[image]

The weird thing now is that it works for just some devices with different OS Systems. It definitly doesn't work on new iPhones 4.

Does anyone has a clue how solve that problem?

Comment: it looks like the posted image. the strange background gaps on the left and the right shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

for iphone 4 you can set the backgroundView.
The group table behaves erratically while working with table cell background.